# Responsive DL and DT layouts

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My problems is that when the browser gets resized at a certain point the layout breaks. For mobile layout I can load another CSS and that's fine, but at 640px it does not look so good.

Is there a way I can fix it? Perhaps there is some known layout that works for this case?

Here is the HTML:

```
​<html>
<dl>
    <dt>Small</dt>
    <dd>Small</dd>
    <dt>Three blind mice</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>    
    <dt>This text is wrapped. But breaks at 640px</dt>
    <dd>Three blind mice, Three blind mice, See how they run</dd>    
</dl>
</html>​
```

And the related CSS:

```
dl  {
    background-color: #D0D;
    overflow: auto;
}

dt  {
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
   text-align: right;
   background-color: #DD0;
}

dd {
   width: 70%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #0DD;
}
```

​
For an example see this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2CtV/). If you resize the browser to smaller scales, the layout gets "messed up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try inline-blocks instead of floats:

```
dl  {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
    background-color: #D0D;
    overflow: auto;
}

dt  {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
   text-align: right;
   background-color: #DD0;
}

dd {
   width: 60%;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #0DD;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L2CtV/3/

Comment: What if you have multiple `dd` per `dt`? This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

it breaks cause of text that doesn't have enough space when you decrease window size. You can add css property `white-space: nowrap;` to `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags to make one line text. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/L2CtV/1/

Also you can use **Media Queries** to set css rules for different window sizes, but it's supported only by modern browsers.

Comment: Close, but I would like it to word wrap but keep the layout. The dt and dd content should always be visible. PS: I'm using media queries. The code above is just to illustrate the issue.